# how to check if menu item is enabled to disabled

Tags: android, if-statement, menuitem, android-toolbar, android-menu

I want to add a function in my app that checks if a menu item is disabled or enabled, if disabled I want my app to do tasl a, if enabled I want my app to do task b.

what I have tried so far;

```
    if (menuItem.setEnabled()==false){
        //do stuff
    } else {
        //do stuff
    }

    if (menuItem.setEnabled(false)){
        //do stuff
    } else {
        //do stuff
    }

    if (menuItem.setEnabled().equals(false)){
        //do stuff
    } else {
        //do stuff
    }
```

I am not sure how I can do this, as whatever I tried doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Have you tried   menuItem.isEnabled()  for the same ?

Comment: please be more clear. Is this from preferences? Are the items checkboxes or similar? And by the way....menuItem.setEnabled() does not exist. Wether it is menuItem.setEnabled(false) (or true) or it is menuItem.isEnabled()....

Comment: Thanks nikk isEnabled did the job. I wasn't sure there was such function, thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
MenuItem mymenu = menu.findItem(R.id.mine_menu);
```

And:

```
if(mymenu.isEnabled()){
        //do something
    }
```

Comment: Can you please describe what You mean with this answer? For my understanding, i can´t see some correlation between the question and Your answer....

Comment: ohh you are right, i thought the problem was in the if and elses.btw, thank you for your attention, fixed.

Comment: Although nikk answered it before you but sadly he did it as a comment :) so I have marked your answer as correct. Thanks for your time and effort!

Comment: @Henry - i was writing and editing as you can see, and that's because i didn't see that user's comment.Though.btw, glad it's working.

Comment: I know you didn't see nikk answer but I was just saying he suggested the same way

Comment: @Henry - ohh no problem, also you may want to take a look at here for completing the answer: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#isEnabled() and : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html goodluck.